# Oracle - How to generate script from sql developer

Tags: oracle

How to take script for schema of the tables, stored procedures of Oracle through SQL Developer tool (SQLPLUS command line interface)?

Comment: This might help someone 

just simply write table_name in sql editor then -->

select table name -->   ​right click
​-->     open declaration
​-->       go to sql tab

Answer (score 63):

[SQL Developer -> Tools -> Database Export...](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm)

Comment: If you have a long list of java sp that you usually do not want to script this way is nightmare.

Comment: what do you mean with "sp" ?

Comment: I assume "sp" means "Stored Procedures".

Answer (score 24):

If you want to see DDL for the objects, you can use

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('OBJECT_TYPE','OBJECT_NAME','OBJECT_OWNER') 
  from dual
/
```

For example this will give you the DDL script for `emp` table.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','EMP','HR') 
  from dual
/
```

You may need to set the `long` type format to big number. For packages, you need to access `dba_source, user_source, all_source` tables. You can query for object name and type to see what code is stored.

Comment: The long being referred here is something like this. "set long 200000 pages 0 lines 131"

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me:

- In SQL Developer, right click the object that you want to generate a script for. i.e. the table name
- Select Quick DLL > Save To File
- This will then write the create statement to an external sql file.

Note, you can also highlight multiple objects at the same time, so you could generate one script that contains create statements for all tables within the database.

Comment: Good answer. One small clarification. At least in the current version of SQL Developer if you select multiple Stored Procedures and do the 'Quick DDL' thing you don't get the body of the SP. To achieve that you have to open multiple Stored Procedures so you can see the part of the tree that refers to the Body and select a number of those and then do a 'Quick DDL'. Thanks for the answer - just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

In Oracle the location that contains information about all database objects including tables and stored procedures is called the Data Dictionary. It is a collection of views that provides you with access to the metadata that defines the database. You can query the Data Dictionary views for a list of desired database objects and then use the functions available in `dbms_metadata` package to get the DDL for each object. Alternative is to investigate the support in `dbms_metadata` to export DDLs for a collection of objects.

For a few pointers, for example to get a list of tables you can use the following Data Dictionary views

- `user_tables` contains all tables owned by the user
- `all_tables` contains all tables that are accessible by the user
- and so on...

Answer (score 3):

use the dbms_metadata package, as described [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_dbms_metadata.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Oracle SQL Developer > View > DBA > Select your connection > Expand > Security > Users > Right click your user > Create like > Fill in fields > Copy SQL script > Close

If your user has object privileges, do this also

Oracle SQL Developer > View > DBA > Select your connection > Expand > Security > Users > Double click your user > Object Privs > Select all data > Right click > Export > Export as text file

Edit that text file to grant object privileges to your user.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

PL SQL Developer -> Tools -> Export User Objects

Select checkboxes: Include privilege and Include storage

Select your file name. Hit export.

You can later use generated export file to create table in another schema.

Comment: SQL Developer and PL/SQL Developer are different programs.

Answer (score 2):

**step 1**. `select * from <tablename>;`

**step 2**. just right click on your output(t.e data) then go to last option export it will give u some extension then click on your required extension then apply u will get new file including data.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer appears to be 'use the dbms_metadata package'.  The axuilliary question is:

> But what if I want to generate a script for all the tables at a time?

And the answer, presumably, is to interrogate the system catalog for the names and owners of all the tables:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', s.tabname, s.tabowner)
  FROM system_catalog_describing_tables AS s
 WHERE ...any conditions that are needed...
```

I'm not sufficiently familiar with Oracle to know the system catalog.  In Informix, which I do know, assuming that there was a procedure `dbms_metadata.get_ddl`, the query would be:

```
SELECT dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', s.tabname, s.owner)
  FROM "informix".systables AS s
 WHERE tabid >= 100 AND tabtype = 'T';
```

In Informix, tabids less than 100 are reserved for the system catalog, and non-tables (views, synonyms, sequences and a few other esoteric things) are excluded by requiring the right 'tabtype'.

Answer (score 1):

I did not know about DMBS_METADATA, but your answers prompted me to create a [utility to script all objects owned by an Oracle user](http://devio.wordpress.com/2009/10/25/introducing-oraddlscript/).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Requires DDTek.Oracle assembly (data provider from datadirect.com).