# Oracle - How to generate DDL script from SQL Developer PROGRAMMATICALLY?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I knew If I need to generate `Oracle DDL script` using `Oracle SQL developer`
I must follow the next steps
[Oracle - How to generate script from sql developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1564347/oracle-how-to-generate-script-from-sql-developer)
*SQL Developer -> Tools -> Database Export......*

But what about
if I need to write script or any other trick
To run it PROGRAMMATICALLY
So it can be scheduled and generated automatically later

Comment: It it a requirement to use SQL Developer as proxy?

Comment: We have a new version of SQL Developer, SQLCl - which is a new kind of SQL*Plus. It has a new command, 'DDL' which generates the ddl as expected, which you can then wrap with a SPOOL command. It's in beta, but i have a slidedeck and video here http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2015/02/oracle-sqlcl-slidedeck-overview-of-our-new-command-line-interface/

Comment: This might help someone just simply write table_name in sql editor then --> select table name --> ​right click ​--> open declaration ​--> go to sql tab

Answer (score 1):

> But what about if i need to write script

If you want to generate a DDL script for a user not manually but via script, then use **DBMS_METADATA**. You could save the below script as a `ddl_script.sql` file and whenever you need to generate the script, simply load the file in **SQL Developer** or run it as script. The output will be the required DDL script.

For example, the following script would give you the complete **DDL** for a **USER**:

```
set long 20000 longchunksize 20000 pagesize 0 linesize 1000 feedback off verify off trimspool on
column ddl format a1000

begin
   dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'SQLTERMINATOR', true);
   dbms_metadata.set_transform_param (dbms_metadata.session_transform, 'PRETTY', true);
end;
/

variable v_username VARCHAR2(30);

exec:v_username := upper('&1');

select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('USER', u.username) AS ddl
from   dba_users u
where  u.username = :v_username
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('TABLESPACE_QUOTA', tq.username) AS ddl
from   dba_ts_quotas tq
where  tq.username = :v_username
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('ROLE_GRANT', rp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_role_privs rp
where  rp.grantee = :v_username
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('SYSTEM_GRANT', sp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_sys_privs sp
where  sp.grantee = :v_username
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('OBJECT_GRANT', tp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_tab_privs tp
where  tp.grantee = :v_username
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_granted_ddl('DEFAULT_ROLE', rp.grantee) AS ddl
from   dba_role_privs rp
where  rp.grantee = :v_username
and    rp.default_role = 'YES'
and    rownum = 1
union all
select to_clob('/* Start profile creation script in case they are missing') AS ddl
from   dba_users u
where  u.username = :v_username
and    u.profile <> 'DEFAULT'
and    rownum = 1
union all
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('PROFILE', u.profile) AS ddl
from   dba_users u
where  u.username = :v_username
and    u.profile <> 'DEFAULT'
union all
select to_clob('End profile creation script */') AS ddl
from   dba_users u
where  u.username = :v_username
and    u.profile <> 'DEFAULT'
and    rownum = 1
/

set linesize 80 pagesize 14 feedback on trimspool on verify on
```

[Source link](http://oracle-base.com/dba/script.php?category=script_creation&file=user_ddl.sql).

> So it can be scheduled and generated automatically later

You could schedule to generate the script at OS level using **CRON** or at database level using **DBMS_SCHEDULER**.